# Google Adwords API v201802 not working

Tags: python, google-ads-api

I am using Adwords API googleads version 201710 and try to migrate to v201802. I didn't change anything except for "version = 'vxxxxxx'" (as I did when migrated to v201710)

```
 targeting_idea_service = client.GetService('TargetingIdeaService', version='v201802')
```

However it returns:

```
Unrecognized version for the AdWords API. Given: v201802 Supported: ['v201702', 'v201705', 'v201708', 'v201710']
```

I think v201802 should be working not. 
[googleads version dates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTGnB.png)
Is there anything I can do to migrate to v201802 now?

Thanks!

Comment: So I upgraded the goolgeads package and it works now

Comment: Can you mark the question as answered?